# grails 2.3.6 fresh install gives "unresolved dependencies" when try to create-app

Tags: grails

as a new grails user, I just downloaded grails 2.3.6, unzipped it, created an env var called GRAILS_HOME pointing to this dir, then added %GRAILS_HOME%/bin to my path (windows 7 pro 64 bit).  Now when I open a new command prompt, and type "grails - version", it says:

Grails version:2.3.6.

However, when I type "grails create-app myapp" in my dev directory, it give a huge error message, the end of which is below. I have trebble checked the path and the GRAILS_HOME are correct.  Unless I missed a magic step, it would seem that the current grails download is seriously broken?

I also tried "grails clean" and tried deleting my user/.grails dir, neither of which made any difference.

```
     D:\dev\grails-2.3.6\plugins\grails-plugin-url-mappings-2.3.6.jar 

           :::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::: 

           ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         :: 

           :::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::: 

           :: org.grails#grails-plugin-rest;2.3.6: not found 

           :: org.grails#grails-plugin-databinding;2.3.6: not found 

           :: org.grails#grails-plugin-i18n;2.3.6: not found 

           :: org.grails#grails-plugin-filters;2.3.6: not found 

           :: org.grails#grails-plugin-gsp;2.3.6: not found 

           :: org.grails#grails-plugin-log4j;2.3.6: not found 

           :: org.grails#grails-plugin-services;2.3.6: not found 

           :: org.grails#grails-plugin-servlets;2.3.6: not found 

           :: org.grails#grails-plugin-url-mappings;2.3.6: not found 

           :::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::: 


 Error Resolve error obtaining dependencies: Failed to resolve dependencies (Se 
 log level to 'warn' in BuildConfig.groovy for more information): 

 org.grails:grails-plugin-rest:2.3.6 
 org.grails:grails-plugin-databinding:2.3.6 
 org.grails:grails-plugin-i18n:2.3.6 
 org.grails:grails-plugin-filters:2.3.6 
 org.grails:grails-plugin-gsp:2.3.6 
 org.grails:grails-plugin-log4j:2.3.6 
 org.grails:grails-plugin-services:2.3.6 
 org.grails:grails-plugin-servlets:2.3.6 
 org.grails:grails-plugin-url-mappings:2.3.6 

(Use --stacktrace to see the full trace) 
 Error Failed to resolve dependencies (Set log level to 'warn' in BuildConfig.g 
oovy for more information): 

 org.grails:grails-scripts:2.3.6 


 Run 'grails dependency-report' for further information.
```

Comment: I also tried running "grails dependency-report" but this also gives the same long error message

Comment: Also tried "grails clean" and deleting .grails from home dir

Comment: searched for one of the missing jars, grails-scripts-2.3.6.jar, and it doesnt exist in the grails dirstirbution.  Its source is there though.  did grails.org make a zip with missing files?

Answer (score 0):

Try again - codehaus.org had  some problems with their site but it's resolved now.

Comment: Still not working. I see part of the problem. for some unknown reason, its looking in an old version directory which no longer exists and is not referenced anywhere.  GRAILS_HOME is pointing to the new version, as is PATH, I deleted home/.grails, and did a grails clean, but its still looking in the old dir:  D:\copy\grails\lib\grails-scripts-2.3.6.jar

Comment: Actually scratch the above comment.  It was just looking in my current dir as part of its search list.